# why i can't access web page source behind user login using HttpWebRequest.Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make windows phone silverlight app that reads web page source. And it does, but only for pages that don't need authentication. I am new to programming and I looked WP8 JumpStart at MVA and their example works fine until I try access specific page that have SSL. For the past two days I tried bunch of thing but nothing worked for me. This is my most recent function that should do the job:

```
private async void ReadPage()
    {
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("usrname" + ":" + "pass");
        string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        request.CookieContainer = container;
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";

        var factory = new TaskFactory();
        var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

        try
        {
            var response = await task;

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string data;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            txtContent.Text = data;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var we = e.InnerException as WebException;
            if (we != null)
            {
                var resp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                var code = resp.StatusCode;
                MessageBox.Show("RespCallback Exception raised! Message: " + we.Message +
                                    " HTTP Status: " + we.Status);
            }
            else
                throw e;
        }
    }
```

Every time I call it, it takes me to the login site which should be already authenticated. At least I think so... I looked at few solutions but nothing helpful for me (or I overlooked something). Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are lots of types of authentication so it could be you are not using the correct type of authentication.  Is the site public?  If so, post it here.

Comment: I tried it on gmail and [mudri](https://mudri.uniri.hr/). Doesn't work with either one. Mudri is Moodle based e-learning sistem of University of Rijeka and it is using [AAI](https://www.switch.ch/aai/about/) authorization model, if I'm correct. It is important to me that second one works...

Comment: Then you are setting the username and password incorrectly (you are setting basic auth).  Find out exactly what type of authentication you require and then you can apply that.  Until you know that.  No one will be able to assist you.

Comment: I find out that site is using HTTPS/SAML protocol. I was looking for solutions online but i didn't understood them very well and I'm not sure if they would work in WP app. @jeff do you have any suggestion? At least some good source where I can learn about this topic...

Comment: I have not played with SAML but this has some client side code you may find useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-Csharp.aspx